# Replicate the go back function of google chrome

Tags: php, session

I am trying to learn how to replicate the go back function of `google chrome` where it will send you back to the `specific page` that you went to.

Here is my case:

This is the main page

```
www.mysite.com/main
```

Now the main page can have a different types of url here is an example:

1. `www.mysite.com/main/type`
2. `www.mysite.com/main/type/pagenum`
3. `www.mysite.com/main/type/category/pagenum`

Now, for example the user visited this url: `www.mysite.com/main/dog/labrador/3`

And then when the user tried to view the link like this(www.mysite.com/view/title-of-the-link), I will have a **go back link button** that returns the user to the `www.mysite.com/main/dog/labrador/3`

I have one solution to solve this using `$_SESSION` variable, for example:

```
if($_GET['type']) {
   $sess_type = '/' . $_GET['type'];
}

if($_GET['category']) {
   $sess_cat = '/' . $_GET['category'];
}

if($_GET['pagenum']) {
   $sess_page = '/' . $_GET['pagenum'];
}

$_SESSION['link'] = '/main' . $sess_type . $sess_cat . $sess_page;
```

This does job a job, I tried to do this idea in my localhost. But I encounter a problem, and that is, for example:

If the last `$_SESSION['link']` is -> `www.mysite.com/main/cat/persian/5` and then the user tried to view again their previous visits from the history. And they re-visited a link like this, for example `www.mysite.com/view/labrador-is-the-title`. Then the `$_SESSSION['link']` that will save on the go back button will be  `www.mysite.com/main/cat/persian/5`. That is the problem that I saw on my solution.

My question is, how can I make this properly ? Any suggestion and advices will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should probably use Javascript for the same. It has a History api that you can use. Now assuming that you want to do this in php itself, you should have a little idea on how exactly the back button works in a browser. It is based on a stack that stores all the urls. Here is a little code to get you started

Call the following code before each php script

```
<?php
  array_push($_SESSION["session_stack"],$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

Call the following code to go back to last page

```
<?php
  $url = array_pop($_SESSION["session_stack"]);
  header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

Basically this maintains a stack on server side similar to browser. When you call the second part of code it simply redirects to last element on the stack.

Comment: @googol8080 again i just demonstrated because you tagged PHP and not javascript. It would be advisable to use javascript for the same :)

Comment: Dude what is `$_SESSION['session_stack']` for ?

Comment: Dude I have some error, array push gives null value

Comment: I think it's session stack

Comment: @googol8080 try var_dump after you insert into $_SESSION to see if the value is being set. I am not sure if array can directly be passed into the same. If that is the case save it as json and use json_encode and decode to access values

Comment: @googol8080 var_dump ? did you use `session_start()` ? and finally i just noticed push will return null only. pop will return the url

Comment: same for pop, but I found an answer in css-tricks and they use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` function